# How do I make sure that a mongoose query has completed before returning the result?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, socket.io

I have this code to get the inventory in my game:

```
async function(username) {
    return await User.findOne({ username: username }).lean().inventory;
}
```

Currently, I run this function in a socket.on that *should* return the data:

```
socket.on('give inventory', function() {
    console.log(connections[socket.id])
    itemmanage.getInventory(connections[socket.id]).then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        socket.emit("get inventory", result);
    })
});
```

However, this doesn't return the data. Instead, it just returns undefined. How do I make it return the data instead of undefined? Everything I've tried still returns undefined.

Comment: It seems that the statement to right of await statement does not return a promise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 async function(username) {
   const data = await User.findOne({ username: username }).lean();
   return data.inventory;
 }

 socket.on('give inventory', async function() {
    try{
        console.log(connections[socket.id])
        const result = await itemmanage.getInventory(connections[socket.id]);
        console.log(result);
        socket.emit("get inventory", result);
    }catch(err){
       //code for handleing error 
    }
 });
```

Comment: that returns Promise {pending}
Edit: Added await to the result const and that fixed it, thanks!